# Do multiprocessing in python dynamically

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7

I have a python file that I am calling via C#. I provide a various number of arguments, one of which is the function that I want to run. I am using multiprocessing with the `daemon` flag set to `True`. I then `join()` the new process with the main with the optional time limit.

Everything works as I want but I want it to be more dynamic so I don't have to have a giant list of if else if statements to decide which function to call.

So, how can I modify

`p = Process(target=dc_906, args=(self.transactionCode, self.givexNum, self.amount, queue))`

to use something like what is below, where `self.function` is the name of the defined function:

`p = Process(target=self.function, args=(self.transactionCode, self.givexNum, self.amount, queue))`

Full python code:

```
queue = mp.Queue()

if self.function == 'dc_906':
    p = Process(target=self.dc_906, args=(self.transactionCode, self.givexNum, self.amount, queue))
elif self.function == 'dc_901':
    p = Process(target=self.dc_901, args=(self.transactionCode, self.givexNum, self.amount, queue))
else:
    p = Process(target=self.dc_907, args=(self.transactionCode, self.givexNum, self.amount, queue))

p.daemon = True

p.start()

p.join(2)

if p.is_alive():
    print 'alive'

print queue.get()

size = queue.qsize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getattr` to dynamically fetch the bound method given a string that describes it:

```
p = Process(target=getattr(self, self.function), args=(...)
```

Comment: That special case was typed wrong. I have fixed it, they should have all been the same.

Comment: Mmkay, straighforward then.

Comment: I am getting an a syntax error, I will screen shot it and post it in my question.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `getattr()`.

Comment: ha, yeah. Just saw that.

Answer (score 1):

Like the [response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python?rq=1), I think you can simply use the `getattr` function which will create a function object from the given object and string, like so:

```
myfunc = getattr(self, self.function)
```

This means you can remove your if statements and try something like the following:

```
p = Process(target=getattr(self, self.function), ...)
```

Don't forget to still keep things comma separated.